# Unable to parse grant statement when trying to duplicate a user

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to duplicate a user using `mysqluserclone` and I am getting the following:

```
ubuntu@****:~$ mysqluserclone --source=<rootuser>:<password>@<db_endpoint> --destination=<rootuser>:<password>@<db_endpoint> '<sourceuser>'@'%' '<destinationuser>'@'%' -vvv
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# Source on <db_endpoint>: ... connected.
# Destination on <db_endpoint>: ... connected.
# Cloning 1 users...
ERROR: Unable to parse grant statement GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'rootuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The privileges for root user are:

```
mysql> show grants for '<rootuser>'@'%';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for <rootuser>@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO '<rootuser>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the privileges for source user are:

```
mysql> show grants for '<sourceuser>'@'%';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for <sourceuser>@%                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '<sourceuser>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>         |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `<mydb>`.* TO ' <sourceuser>'@'%' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone help with how to resolve this issue, or suggest another way to create this user?